# Problems with push notification on Enterprise environment

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, enterprise

I am facing a problem with Push notification, and the problem occurs only on clients Enterprise environment.

The problem is as follows: when I am testing on my side (development and not distribution) I receive notification and `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` is called every time and works perfectly through the following cases:

1. When app is not opened (not in memory or suspended apps), and not in background nor foreground
2. When app is opened but in background.
3. When app is in foreground.

But when the client tries it on his environment (after mdm wrapping), the following happens in each case:

Case 1: Works successfully, and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method gets called fine.

Case 2: Receives notification, but `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called.

Case 3: I don't see any notification neither in notification centre and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called also.

I searched for anything that could help, and I only found that there is this `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` maybe be a better replacement.

Any other suggestions? Any thing to check or to consider? Is it maybe an iOS related issue? Caused by MDM configuration (a long shot I know)?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of push are you sending?  A silent push (content-available=1)

Comment: No, I believe it is not silent. How can I check ?

Comment: Do you specify the content-available key?  If not then it is not silent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used this method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` which suited well.